# Verify a JWT Token issued by Entra AD App Registration in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I right now have an Entra/Azure AD App registration that is being used by a small Angular SPA to authenticate it to an ASP.NET Core Web API.

When I decode the JWT, the `iss` (issuer) is:

```
 "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/64..............a21/",
```

and in my `Program.cs`, I have:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["https://login.microsoftonline.com/64..............a21"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["http://localhost:5036/"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey
        (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["?????"])), //this is what i feel like I am missing
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
    };
});
```

I am getting http error 401's when running my Angular app in local dev mode and the API locally too. I was following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/quickstart-register-app) to make the app registration.

So my question is - how can I get the signing key so that my app can validate JWT tokens from Azure.

Comment: You're using `AddJwtBearer()` instead of an OIDC-compatible authentication scheme. The `AddJwtBearer()` scheme doesn't verify PKI keys. Instead, either use `AddOpenIdConnect()` (with suitable configuration) _or_ use [the Entra-specific `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp()` extension method which handles a lot of the config for you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/tutorial-web-app-dotnet-sign-in-prepare-app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only need to use code like this:

```cs
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = ...;
    options.Audience = ...;
}
```

Your wider problem looks to be that you are receiving the wrong type of JWT access token, with a `nonce` in the JWT header.

To fix it you need to `expose an API scope` from an API registration, then include it in the API permissions of your Angular client. During its OIDC flow the client should then request that scope. My example SPA uses these settings:

```json
{
    "app": {
        "apiBaseUrl":             "https://api.mycompany.com/api"
    },
    "oauth": {
        "authority":              "https://login.microsoftonline.com/7f071fbc-8bf2-4e61-bb48-dabd8e2f5b5a/v2.0",
        "clientId":               "e9a29a01-21b4-4533-bae6-438141ebc05c",
        "redirectUri":            "https://web.mycompany.com/spa/",
        "postLogoutRedirectUri":  "https://web.mycompany.com/spa/loggedout.html",
        "scope":                  "openid api://552b475c-471d-43a1-9dfe-f6b895931110/investments"
    }
}
```

Step 4 of my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/azure-ad-troubleshooting/) has further details.

Comment: Hey thank you - this blog post was very in-depth. I cannot get rid of the nonce though - so I have an app registration for the Angular SPA using the [Angular MSAL guide](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular)

`return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: '52b...5e',
      authority:  'https://login.microsoftonline.com/6432...a21',
      redirectUri: '/',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: '/login',
    },
`
under that app reg I have the exposed API permissions from the other app reg from the API

Comment: What scope is your client requesting? I added a note on that to my answer.

Comment: I went back and re-read the blog post again - I was a tad confused about what values to put where but on the C# side this worked in my appSettings

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "ourName.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "64...21",
    "ClientId": "de...78"
  },
```


and then program.cs
```builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd");```